# Git command to show latest branch name to have been merged into master?

Tags: git

Git command to show latest branch name to have been merged into master?

I am wondering if there is a Git command that can do this?

I can list the merged branches, but this doesn't reveal the latest one.  Also, interestingly, branches created from tags are displayed in the result, which also isn't what I want:

```
git branch -vv --merged master
```

Comment: This sounds like an opportunity to use git log one-liner with a grep on top and alias it. Would that get done what you want?

Comment: I want to use it in a shell script.

Comment: I don't believe this request is possible. Branch information is not saved in the object storage of the repository. Branches are metadata on top of this, and can be manipulated and deleted easily.

Comment: Yeah, i tried using sort options on this command, but they don't work.

Comment: Yes, that answered my question.  Thanks!